# Transposing dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
ID<-c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")  
x<-c(0,1,2,1,1)
y<-c(2,1,1,1,1)
z<-c(0,1,1,0,0)
mydata<-data.frame(ID,x,y,z)
```

What is best way of transposing the data or converting columns into rows without converting the numeric values into characters or without any error. The Original data has around 1000 columns and 50 rows.

Comment: Did you try to reshape wide-to-long? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

First, I tryed to use the base R-function t() for transposing your dataframe. t() changes the numeric values to character and creates new names. So I needed to transform it correctly by matching the names and changing the type back to numeric:

```
# original dataframe here
ID <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")
x <- c(0,1,2,1,1)
y <- c(2,1,1,1,1)
z <- c(0,1,1,0,0)
mydata <- data.frame(ID,x,y,z)

# create a new frame to hold the flipped data.
# It'll have one more column than there are rows in your original, to fit all your IDs as headers.
transposed_data <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = nrow(mydata) + 1, nrow = ncol(mydata) - 1)), c('Variable', as.character(mydata$ID)))

# We'll label the first column 'Variable' and fill it with your original column names, minus 'ID'.
transposed_data$Variable <- names(mydata)[-1]

# loop through and fill in the rest. For each original column, copy its values over.
for (i in 2:ncol(mydata)) {
  transposed_data[i-1, -1] <- as.numeric(mydata[, i])
}

# final dataframe
print(transposed_data)
  Variable A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1        x  0  1  2  1  1
2        y  2  1  1  1  1
3        z  0  1  1  0  0

str(transposed_data)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Variable: chr  "x" "y" "z"
 $ A1      : num  0 2 0
 $ A2      : num  1 1 1
 $ A3      : num  2 1 1
 $ A4      : num  1 1 0
 $ A5      : num  1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
mydata = 
  mydata[-1] |> 
  t() |> 
  as.data.frame() |> 
  `colnames<-`(mydata$ID)
mydata = cbind(Var = rownames(mydata), mydata)
rownames(mydata) = NULL
```

gives

```
> mydata
  Var A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
1   x  0  1  2  1  1
2   y  2  1  1  1  1
3   z  0  1  1  0  0
```

Check the result of `lapply(mydata, class)`.

---

Data:

```
mydata = data.frame(ID = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), x = c(0,1,2,1,1),
                    y = c(2,1,1,1,1), z = c(0,1,1,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
> t(`row.names<-`(mydata[-1], mydata$ID))
  A1 A2 A3 A4 A5
x  0  1  2  1  1
y  2  1  1  1  1
z  0  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thank you but i am curious to know that whynot simply as.data.frame(t(mydata) ? And is there anyway to check whether the transposing did correctly ?

Comment: To my understanding, this results in a matrix, and only works if all values of `mydata` are of the same class. A `matrix` in R cannot have more than one class -- in contrast to a `data.frame`. Given your toy data, this is why `as.data.frame(t(mydata))` does not work, but `as.data.frame(t(mydata[-1]))` does. Finally, we are often faced with additional work to move the row names to a separate column.

Comment: @Aryh if you use `t(...)` directly, the data.frame will be processed as a matrix, and all numeric entries will be coerced to characters due to the type of entries in the `ID` column

Comment: @Friede yes, that's right and thank you for elaborating the details :)